# Program runs with no errors but button wont open

Tags: java, android

I have been following the mybringback tutorials on youtube and I tried implementing what I learned. Trying to get a button on my main page to open another page. Finally got the program to run without errors but now when I press the button nothing opens.

Main .xml file where my button is

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnChpt3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:text="Appearance and Grooming Policies"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    android:gravity="center" 
    />
```

Name of .xml file im trying to get to is chapter3.xml

Menu.java

```
package com.th3ramr0d.learnar670_1;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Menu extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button chapterThree = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChpt3);

    chapterThree.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        // @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new Intent("com.th3ramr0d.learnar670_1.CHAPTER3"));

        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
}
```

}

And my manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.th3ramr0d.learnar670_1"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".Menu"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.th3ramr0d.learnar670_1.MENU" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".Chapter3"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.th3ramr0d.learnar670_1.CHAPTER3" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

So button ided as btnChpt3 wont open up my .xml file named chapter3.xml. Thanks for the help.

Here is my Chapter3.java

```
 package com.th3ramr0d.learnar670_1;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.os.Bundle;

 public class Chapter3 extends Activity{

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.chapter3);
 }


 }
```

Here is my MainActivity.java

```
 package com.th3ramr0d.learnar670_1;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;


 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 }




 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }
 }
```

Comment: Is your `Menu` code being executed? I see you have `activity_main` layout there and not e.g. `activity_menu` - it's possible you have the `activity_main` also displayed by your main activity and no onclick listener there.

Comment: Sorry, but im a noob to this stuff. Can you break what your saying down for me?

Comment: Looking at your `Manifest`, the activity that launches first is your `MainActivity`. Were you able to process a button click there? Could you update the question with that code as well?

Comment: Could you confirm that the button is in `Main.xml` or `activity_main.xml`? In you questions its mentioned `Main.xml`

Comment: Try to remove this if not useful <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.th3ramr0d.learnar670_1.CHAPTER3" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

Comment: Sorry I worded it poorly. I meant the main .xml file as in the home screen. The button is in activity_main.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy this and paste in your `AndroidManifest` and try,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.th3ramr0d.learnar670_1"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Menu"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Chapter3"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.th3ramr0d.learnar670_1.CHAPTER3" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

To help you understand the problem,

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

The code above in the `AndroidManifest` defines the activity to be launced when the App Icon is pressed. As per your earlier manifest, it launches the activity `MainActivity` which also sets it `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` by default as the IDE creates a `Hello World` program.

So when you launch you app, its `MainActivity` (that looks the same layout you have designed) which is loading and not `Menu` activity which you want to load. Hence making few changes in the manifest where we declare the `Menu` activity as the launcher now launches `Menu` activity which has the piece of code to process your button click.

I hope this helped!

Comment: I understand what your saying and that helps a lot. However, that code still doesn't work. Now when I run it on my phone and nexus 7 the program never appears and the icon is never shown for me to start it. I can see it running in the settings/apps but I cant get the program to open.

Comment: Could you please clean the project and run again `Project -> Clean`

Comment: And also you can delete `MainActivity.java` from your project as it serves no purpose

Comment: Ok its working :) What happened was I renamed Menu.java to MainMenu.java because I thought the name was responsible somehow. So I edited your code to reflect my class name but I thought it had to be the same on both android:name=".Menu" and android.intent.action.MAIN" so i changed it to be android.intent.action.MAINMENU". Anyways onto my question. Why is the extention of android.intent.action.MAIN have to be MAIN? I guess I'm not fully comprehending this part. Thanks.

Comment: Happy its working for you. I would recommend you to watch some tutorials from `youtube slidenerd or smartherd`. They helped me a lot.

Comment: And also I found this for you https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-beginners/ET6A02FIJm8

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can try a more convenient way of starting activities inside your application:

`startActivity(new Intent(Menu.this, Chapter3.class))`

Also you can read more how it works here:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Answer (score 0):

Good day.

Try replacing the line :

```
startActivity(new Intent("com.th3ramr0d.learnar670_1.CHAPTER3"));
```

with the code below :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Menu.this, Chapter3.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Try reverting your code to the original code, copy your layout activity_main.xml and rename it menu.xml.

now in the layout menu.xml change this line:

```
android:text="Appearance and Grooming Policies"
```

to:

android:text="Go to menu"

and the line:

```
android:id="@+id/btnChpt3"
```

with:

```
android:id="@+id/btnMenu"
```

and replace the line:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

in Menu.java with:

setContentView(R.layout.menu.xml);

finally in MainActivity.java add the following to your oncreate method:

Button btnGoToMenu = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMenu);

btnGoToMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
// @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Menu.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

});

and re-run the application.

Comment: Still the same effect. Nothing opens.

Comment: I assume you are getting to the Menu activity correctly? Could you post your Chaper3.java class so that we may see the code?

Comment: I also assume the app does not crash?

Comment: Correct. It doesnt crash. Doesnt give any errors. When I press the button it just doesnt do anything.

Comment: My intention here is to show you how different layouts link to different activities, and how naming conventions can help you avoid some of the confusion experienced here. Also +1 to codePG for a great answer.

Comment: If by +1 you mean hit the up arrow for his answer then I would like to but I don't have enough rep I already tried :(

Comment: That is why I commented it myself, as I can not +1 him myself either. I hope the answers helped you gain a better understanding. Have a good day.