# Putting multiple onClickListener and OnClick in the same activity

Tags: java, android

I am trying to setup multiple buttons but I seem to be having trouble doing it. I have 2 onClickListener functions in the same activity. Am I right in doing this or should this be done some other way? btnChpt3 works but when I input the onclicklistener for btnChpt3_1 it force closes as soon as it opens. Thanks.

MainMenu.java

```
 package com.th3ramr0d.learnar670_1;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;

 public class MainMenu extends Activity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button chapterThree = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChpt3); 

    chapterThree.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            startActivity(new Intent(MainMenu.this, Chapter3.class));

        }
    });


    Button chapterThree_1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChpt3_1);

    chapterThree_1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            startActivity(new Intent(MainMenu.this, Chapter3_1.class));

        }
    });

 }


 @Override
 protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
 }

 }
```

So I added a new class to handle the buttons on a sub menu page. But now I am running into the same problem I was previously where the button wont open. I am guessing  its because the code isnt being ran for some reason.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.th3ramr0d.learnar670_1"
 android:versionCode="1"
 android:versionName="1.0" >

 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainMenu"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

   <activity
        android:name=".SubMenuChapter3"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".Chapter3"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.th3ramr0d.learnar670_1.CHAPTER3" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>



    <activity
        android:name=".Chapter4"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.th3ramr0d.learnar670_1.CHAPTER4" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>


 </application>

 </manifest>
```

You can see here that my .MainMenu launches. I am guessing that means it launches at startup. So the  button works. However, now I want the button associated with .SubMenuChapter3 to launch and it does nothing. Here [Program runs with no errors but button wont open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26839424/program-runs-with-no-errors-but-button-wont-open/26841045?noredirect=1#comment42248614_26841045) you can see I had the same problem until codepg was nice enough to tell me where I was wrong. But I want to use several of these sub menus so how would I do that?

Comment: Your code is totally fine. Are you sure chapterThree_1 isn't null?

Comment: Most likely your call to `findViewById(R.id.btnChpt3_1)` is returning `null` which would mean your call to `chapterThree_1.setOnClickListener(...)` would throw an NPE. Check your layout XML file and also post logcat.

Comment: The buttons are in two different .xml files. The button that works is in my activity_main.xml and the second button is in chapter3.xml Could this be the causes of this and how would I fix it?

Comment: @dtrodriguez : Yes. That is your problem. You can only use `findViewById(...)` to find references to views that are in your current layout. In this case the layout is created using activity_main.xml and set using `setContentView(...)`. It's not possible to find the other button as it doesn't exist in that layout file.

Comment: So my next question is how would I do that? Do I need to create a new class for that set of buttons?

Comment: @dtrodriguez : You'd put the `chapterThree_1` code in to whatever `Activity` is using your `chapter3.xml` layout file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem, after reading, is that you are referencing a button that you have created in another layout which you are not inflating.

In the `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` you are inflating `activity_main` so you can only have onclick listeners for buttons and elements in that xml.

Make sure that you add `btnChpt3` in this xml or if this button is supposed too be in another layout then have another activity or fragment control that layout by inflating it.

Right now this method `Button chapterThree = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChpt3);` is returning a null pointer exception.

Answer (score 1):

I can see from your comments that you are inflating the view activity_main but Button with id bthChpt3_1 is in another file. This is an error as you can use findViewById(R.id.buttonId) to find the id of a button which exists within the view you are using. Since the button is in another xml file, it will throw a null pointer exception.